# figure out all derangement of array

Tags: c, algorithm, permutation

This is a programme that try to figure out all derangement of array `{10, 11, 12, 13}`

But it doesn’t work, because when it comes to `depth==0, i==0` and `Peano[]=={0, 1, 2, 3}`, the for loop didn’t end then i decrements to be -1. What hell is going on?

```
      #include<stdio.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>
        unsigned long long derange(int *array, int LEN, _Bool display, int *Peano, unsigned depth);
        int main(void){
        int i ,LEN=4, *Peano=malloc(sizeof(int));
        int array[4]={10,11,12,13};
        for(i=0; i<LEN; i++)Peano[i]=i;
        derange(array, LEN, 1, Peano, 0);
        printf("this derangement of the array total of %llu.\n", derange(array, LEN, 0, Peano, 0));
        return 0;}

            unsigned long long derange(int *array, int LEN, _Bool display, int *Peano, unsigned depth){
                    int i, temp;
                    unsigned long long count=0;
                    if(depth==LEN){
                            if(display){
                                    for(i=0; i<LEN; i++)
                                            fprintf(stdout, "%d\040", array[i]);
                                    putchar('\n');}
                            return 1;}
                    for(i=LEN-1; i>=depth; i--){
                            if(i==Peano[depth])continue;
                            temp=Peano[i]; Peano[i]=Peano[depth]; Peano[depth]=temp;
                            temp=array[i]; array[i]=array[depth]; array[depth]=temp;
                            count += derange(array, LEN, display, Peano, depth+1);
                            temp=Peano[i]; Peano[i]=Peano[depth]; Peano[depth]=temp;
                            temp=array[i]; array[i]=array[depth]; array[depth]=temp;}
                    return count;}
```

Comment: Please clean up the presentation of your code. What's the point of allocating `Peano`? You want it to be an array of 4 (or `LEN`) ints, but you only allocate storage for one int. Why not use `int Peano[LEN]`?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
int i ,LEN=4, *Peano=malloc(sizeof(int));
```

you allocate space for a single integer to `Peano`. `Peano` is an index array that goes alongside `array`, of length 4. Just create it as automatic variable on the stack:

```
int Peano[4];
```

There's another problem with your loop in `derange`:

```
for (i = LEN - 1; i >= depth; i--) ...
```

That is a loop tat counts the signed int `i` downwards. Your variable `depth` is `unsigned`, however. That means that in the comparson `i >= depth` the signed `i` is "promoted" to unsigned in. If `depth` is zero, that comparison will always be true, because `i >= 0` is true for all unsigned ints per definition.

You can fix this by either making `depth` an `int` instead of an `unsigned` or by using a downwards loop ariant that works for signed and unsigned types:

```
for (i = LEN; i-- > depth; ) ...
```

or, if you don't like the empty update clause

```
i = LEN;
while (i-- > depth) ...
```

Comment: what conditions will int type convert to unsigned type? what conditions will  unsigned  type convert to int type? because c primer plus said "When appearing in an expression, char and short, both signed and unsigned, are
automatically converted to int or, if necessary, to unsigned int. "

Comment: If two integers have the same "[rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854596/integer-conversion-rank-and-promotion)", but one is unsigned and the other is signed, the common type is the unsigned type of that rank, in your case `unsigned int`.

Comment: In general, your code suffers from a certain untidiness, not only in presentation but also in logic. It is okay to use an unsigned type for things that cannot be negative like array sizes and positions, but if you use unsigned, you should use unsigned throughout, that is for the `peano` array and its sizes. If you use unsigned, make sure that your counters don't get below zero, because if so, they will be regarded as very large numbers. Use the loops I've shown in my answer.